# MySQL lower_case_table_names causes PHP connection error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

In MySQL, the `lower_case_table_names` global variable determines whether letter case is preserved when a table name is written to disk, and whether matching of table names is case sensitive.  According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names):

> If you are using InnoDB or MySQL Cluster (NDB) tables, you should set
>   this variable to 1 on all platforms to force names to be converted to
>   lowercase.

My site is on a Apache 2.4 with MySQL 5.6.23 and PHP 5.5.25. Most of my tables are MyISAM but I would like to convert them to InnoDB. In accordance with the directive above, I tried to set `lower_case_table_names=1` in MySQL's config file.  However, after restarting the server, I can no longer connect to the database from my PHP code using the mysqli extension.  The code `$this->mysqli = new \mysqli($host,$user,$pwd,$db_name,$port);` returns `mysqli->connect_error = "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"`.  I am certain that the login credentials are good for the following reasons:

- Outside of the PHP environment, I can connect to the database using
  the same credentials, with a remote tool (SQLyog).
- If I remove `lower_case_table_names=1` line from the config file and
  restart the server, things work again.

During the MySQL server startup sequence -- when `lower_case_table_names=1` -- the error log shows 3 warnings:

- `[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please
  use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see
  documentation for more details).`
- `[Warning] 'db' entry '%_ldap_ou=addressbook cpldap@localhost' had
  database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because
  lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this
  privilege using REVOKE.`
- `[Warning] 'db' entry 'logaholicdb_host logaholic@localhost' had
  database in mixed case that has been forced to lowercase because
  lower_case_table_names is set. It will not be possible to remove this
  privilege using REVOKE.`

There are also several `[Note]` entries logged under both configs. When the `lower_case_table_names=1` line is removed, only the 1st warning appears. The user getting denied access has the following privileges on the database in question (result of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';`)

> - GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6DF294D9BAA539074CFC4DD08E77909FE53CFCE1'
> - GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE
>     VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `my_db`.* TO
>     'username'@'localhost'

Why is the connection failing and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: First take backup of your db (all tales) by mysqldump command.

Step2: Now change your configuration setting for lower case.

Step3: Now restart mysql service.

Step4: Now restore the backup.

By this all tables name written on disk in lower case by default and even you can call them either by lower/upper/camel case but actually they will be stored on server in lower case.

Comment: (1) In your query you put `my_pass_in_lower_case`.  Why? (2) I've updated the OP to show what privileges the user already has. So permissions are already there. Do you still think I should assign permissions again?

Comment: I figured out that the connection problem was not actually the reason my development code wasn't working.  The connection problem was introduced during debugging because in debugging, I was using the development login credentials but trying to connect to a test database with different users.  I think the root cause of the problem has to do with all table names being automatically converted to lower case before the server executed each SQL query.  More details in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, here is what I've found.

The problem breaking my site was not actually with establishing a connection to MySQL. The error that denied me access earlier was caused by another issue. My debugging session was querying a development database with different access permissions, so when debugging the problem I thought the failed connection was the cause -- it was a problem with the debugging itself.  Something else was actually breaking my site.

Eventually I figured out that setting `lower_case_table_names=1` seems to break SQL query execution on any table whose name has a capital letter.  For instance, I have a table named `tblCountries`.  If I run query `SELECT * FROM tblCountries`, MySQL returns error `tblcountries does not exist`.  Notice the error has lowercase 'c'.

Queries on a table name with no upper case seem to work just fine: `SELECT * FROM user` works because that table name (`user`) has no uppercase.  So I tried renaming `tblCountries` to `tblcountries` with query `RENAME TABLE 'tblCountries' to 'tblcountries'` but MySQL failed with error `Can't find file: './db_name/tblcountries.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)`.

Both of these issues seem to suggest that the server is putting everything in lower case before running the query.  In fact, on disc although there is no file `tblcountries.frm`, the file `tblCountries.frm` exists along with files `tblCountries.MYD` and `tblCountries.MYI`.  If I manually rename all three files by replacing 'C' with 'c', the same query `SELECT * FROM tblCountries` executes successfully.

So I have at least two options but don't know which is better or if there is a 3rd best option:

1) remove `lower_case_table_names=1` option to make the server respect letter case when executing queries; then execute `RENAME TABLE 'tblCountries' to 'tblcountries'` with every table to remove all uppercases; finally when all uppercases have been removed, re-insert `lower_case_table_names=1`.

2) Just manually rename files on disk as I did with `tblCountries.frm`.  This seems like the easier method but I don't know enough about MySQL to know whether it will cause me more problems down the line.